# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited channel.send(embed=embed)

Tags: python

I can't figure out what the error is.
I'm trying to send values (`MyModal2`) to a channel (`interaction.guild.get_channel('number_channel')`) using `discord.Embed`... But in the end it gives an error:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'Messageable.send' was never awaited channel.send(embed=embed)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

```
class MyModal2(ui.Modal, title = 'Application for membership'):
    new_client = ui.TextInput(label = 'Your first name last name', placeholder='example: Zenicu Lena',style = discord.TextStyle.short)
    new_client_id = ui.TextInput(label = 'Your staticID', placeholder='example:#45970',style = discord.TextStyle.short)
    buissnes = ui.TextInput(label = 'Where you work', placeholder='example: Government ',style = discord.TextStyle.short)
    about = ui.TextInput(label = 'Date/Time', placeholder='example: 23.12 / 23:15 ', style = discord.TextStyle.short)

    async def on_submit( self, interaction: discord.Interaction):

        channel = interaction.guild.get_channel( ... )

        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="New application for membership",
            description= f'1.{self.new_client.value},\n2. {self.new_client_id.value},\n3.{self.buissnes.value},\n4.{self.about.value}',
            color = discord.Color.purple()
            )
        embed.set_author(name = self.user.nick)

        channel.send(embed=embed)
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'{interaction.user.mention} - Thx for your!',  ephemeral= True)

@bot.tree.command(name = 'invite', description = 'Application for membership')
async def modal(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    polit_modal = MyModal2()
    polit_modal.user = interaction.user
    await interaction.response.send_modal(polit_modal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `await` before awaitable object/function

`channel.send(embed=embed)` -> `await channel.send(embed=embed)`